# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: ооп, php, mysql

Вот выдает ошибку:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object

```
include "DataBase.class.php";

$opts = array(
        'user'    => 'root',
        'pass'    => '',
        'db'      => 'school',
        'charset' => 'utf8'
);

$db = new SafeMySQL($opts); // with some of the default settings overwritten

class School
{
    protected $fullname;
    protected $rating;
    protected $about;

    public function __construct($fullname, $rating, $about)
    {
        $this->fullname = $fullname;

        $this->rating = $rating;

        $this->about = $about;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO 'school' ('fullname', 'rating', 'about' ) VALUES ('$this->fullname', '$this->rating', '$this->about')");
    }
};
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: > Что делаю не так?

Пытаетесь достучаться до переменной, лежащей вне области видимости. Область видимости для метода - это объявленные классы/функции, параметры, $this, но не внешние переменные. Поэтому $db внутри метода не существует, надо его туда поместить с помощью global, параметра, или, самое лучшее, dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

Просто маленький тест для демонстрации:

```
$db = 'db';
class School
{
    public function test_db() { print_r( $db ); }
};
$school = new School;
$school->test_db();
```

Вывод:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db in /home/klopp/dev/1.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/klopp/dev/1.php:0
PHP   2. School->test_db() /home/klopp/dev/1.php:9
```

Дальше пояснять нужно?

*Обновление*

[[@Александр Клюев](/users/19628/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/19628/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B5%D0%B2), потому что в PHP такой код:

```
$db = 1;
function test_db() { $db = 2; }
echo $db; // выведется 1
```

аналогичен сишному:

```
int db = 1;
void test_db() { int db = 2; }
printf( "%d\n", db ); // выведется 1
```

То есть внутри функции переменная `$db` объявляется как локальная, и доступ к глобальной `$db` нужно организовывать отдельно.

P.S. [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Да, а то до меня не дошло

Comment: Чуть выше уже объяснили - переменную `$db` из метода класса просто не видно. Но это ещё не всё: я не знаю что внутри `DataBase.class.php`, но есть шанс что эта переменная и в области видимости может быть не определена. То есть может сначала понадобиться проверка `$db = new SafeMySQL($opts); if( !$db ) { /* продолжать не можем */ }`

Comment: Но почему?  Я же объявил до того, как вызвал

Comment: @klopp, насколько знаю, невозможно проинициализироват класс в null, php либо упадет, либо создаст экземпляр.

@Александр Клюев, потому что там, где обращаетесь, не видно того, где объявили.

Comment: Т.е нужно было перед этим объявить? 
$school = new School;
$school->save();
?

Answer (score 1):

[[@Александр Клюев](/users/19628/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/19628/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B5%D0%B2), еще раз

У каждого метода и функции своя область видимости, куда **не попадают** переменные из родительской области видимости (кроме замыканий с use). Поэтому $db, являющаяся внешней переменной для метода, из метода недоступна. Ее надо так или иначе в метод передать, способ "в лоб" такой:

```
class Superclass
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function testDb()
    {
        $this->db->test();
    }
}
```